# Does this patent also include HTML browsers on a mobile device

Tags: us20140288683

In reference to the patent: [US20140288683](https://www.google.com/patents/US20140288683)

There are so many applications that do live stats on mobile devices.  Does this patent have the ability to shutdown those hundreds of companies that have done the same thing.  Also wht if a website had the ability to do this, can a browser on a mobile device account for breaching the patent just because live stats are on a mobile browser?  Yahoo was doing live stats on a mobile browser far before this patent was created.

[image]

Comment: It's only an "Application" not a "patent", and I suspect it will be rejected.

Comment: Can you explain what that means?  They have it listed at the bottom of their site as if it was a patent.

Comment: Wikipedia has an article on [applicaitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patent_application), essentially an application is just a official document you complete detailing what you think you've invented (a bit like a driving licence application). If the patent office examiner finds the claims in your document to be non obvious, not already known to them (a patent for the wheel was granted in Australia in 2001), and in a patentable field....., you may end up with a patent being "granted", or the examiner  offering a few detail why a grant can't be made in it's present state.

Comment: Why would they have text at the bottom of their site stating its a Patent?

Comment: Because that [one](https://www.google.co.uk/patents/US8731458?dq=8731458&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zmlLVYPJFvKN7AbP6IDQAw&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA) was granted.

Comment: I suspect it could easily be challenged, in the light of [Alice](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_Corp._v._CLS_Bank_International), if not by the fact the 1996 Olympics (an amateur event) offered live results via a website.

Comment: FYI: http://www.nytimes.com/1996/07/29/business/ibm-seeks-its-footing-after-atlanta-stumble.html

Comment: Yea I find it very odd it could of been granted.

Comment: Wheel successfully patented 2001 ;-)

Comment: What do you mean by Wheel?

Comment: Round object, often used for transportation, have a Google.

Comment: Oh sarcasm, thanks, thought it was some patent lingo.

Comment: Have a read: http://www.newscientist.com/article/dn965-wheel-patented-in-australia.html#.VUvHGNNViko

Comment: "Innovation patents" in Australia are entirely unexamined. It's almost a pure registration system (though I suppose there might be some weak profanity filters and what not). Any "innovation patent" must be examined before it can be enforced. So, nobody "pulled a fast one" on an Australian patent examiner by patenting the wheel.

Comment: How do you go about discrediting a patent?